# WordPress - Overwriting a template plugin Shortcode

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I'm new to php and wordpress. 
When I edit an icon box from the theme in the admin panel, i have a few fields, like "title" and "content". The title is inside `<h4> </h4>` and content is inside `<p> 
 </p>`
I need to add another `<p style='iconbox_price'></p>` after the content, so i can edit it in the admin panel.

This is the code for the iconbox. How can i add this to it, so it would work out.

```
<?php
function easyweb_webnus_iconbox( $attributes, $content = null ) {

extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    "type"=>'',
    'icon_title'=>'',
    'icon_link_url'=>'',
    'icon_link_text'=>'',
    "icon_name"=>'',
    "iconbox_content"=>'',
    "icon_size"=>'',
    "icon_color"=>'',
    "title_color"=>'',
    "content_color"=>'',
    "link_color"=>'',
    "icon_image"=>'',
    "featured"=>'',
    "border_left"=>'',
    "border_right"=>'',
), $attributes));
ob_start();

$type =  ( $type == 0 ) ? '' : $type ;

$iconbox_style = $type17_start_wrap = $type17_end_wrap = '';
if ( $type==17 ) {
    $iconbox_style = ( !empty($icon_color) ) ? ' style="color: ' . esc_attr($icon_color) . '"' : '' ;
    $type17_start_wrap = '<div class="icon-wrap" style="background-color:' . esc_attr($icon_color) . '">';
    $type17_end_wrap   = '</div>';
}

$iconbox22_class = '';
if ( $type == 22 ) {
    $iconbox22_class .= $featured ? ' ' . $featured : '';
    $iconbox22_class .= $border_left ? ' ' . $border_left : '';
    $iconbox22_class .= $border_right ? ' ' . $border_right : '';
}

echo '<article class="icon-box' . $type . $iconbox22_class . '" ' . $iconbox_style . '>';

    if(!empty($icon_name) && $icon_name != 'none') :
        if(!empty($icon_link_url))
            echo '' . $type17_start_wrap . '<a href="' . esc_url($icon_link_url) . '">'  . do_shortcode(  "[icon name='$icon_name' size='$icon_size' color='$icon_color']" ).'</a>' . $type17_end_wrap . '';
        else
            echo $type17_start_wrap . do_shortcode(  "[icon name='$icon_name' size='$icon_size' color='$icon_color']" ) . $type17_end_wrap;
    elseif(!empty($icon_image)) :
        if(is_numeric($icon_image)){
            $icon_image = wp_get_attachment_url( $icon_image );
        }
        if(!empty($icon_link_url))
            echo "<a href='$icon_link_url'>" . '<img src="'.$icon_image.'" alt="" />' . '</a>' ;
        else
            echo '<img src="'.$icon_image.'" alt="" />';
    endif;

    $title_style = !empty($title_color)?' style="color:'.$title_color.'"':'';
     echo '<h4'.$title_style.'>' . $icon_title . '</h4>';
     $content_style = !empty($content_color)?' style="color:'.$content_color.'"':'';
     echo '<p'.$content_style.'>'.$iconbox_content .'</p>' ;
     $link_style = !empty($link_color)?' style="color:'.$link_color.'"':'';
     echo (!empty($icon_link_url) &&  (!empty($icon_link_text)) )?"<a".$link_style." class=\"magicmore\" href=\"{$icon_link_url}\">{$icon_link_text}</a>":'';

echo '</article>';

$out = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$out = str_replace('<p></p>','',$out);
    return $out;
 }
 add_shortcode('iconbox', 'easyweb_webnus_iconbox');
```

In html this is the code, that is generated:

```
<article class="icon-box14">
    <a href="/razrabotka-saitov/">
    <i class="sl-screen-desktop" style=" font-size:42px;"></i>
    </a>
    <h4 style="height: 22px;">Title</h4>
    <p style="height: 116px;">Content<br></p>
    <a class="magicmore" href="#">More</a>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in my case. Maybe it will help somebody else. I had to edit two files. In my case this is where the first file was located.

```
wp-content/plugins/'theme'-shortcodes/shortcodes/iconbox.php
```

I tried to look for where comes the variable `$iconbox_content` and found it in  getting extracted in the code above from an array at this point:

```
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        "type"=>'',
        'icon_title'=>'',
        'icon_link_url'=>'',
        'icon_link_text'=>'',
        "icon_name"=>'',
        "iconbox_content"=>'',
        "icon_size"=>'',
        "icon_color"=>'',
        "title_color"=>'',
        "content_color"=>'',
        "link_color"=>'',
        "icon_image"=>'',
        "featured"=>'',
        "border_left"=>'',
        "border_right"=>'',
    ), $attributes));
```

So i searched through all the wordpress directory files, because i did not even have an idea where can i find it. 
And found it in the `themes => 'my theme' => 'my theme' => visualcomposer => shortcodes` directory as `03-iconbox.php`

I had there different arrays such as this:

```
    array(
        "type"=>'textarea',
        "heading"=>esc_html__('Content', 'ew'),
        "param_name"=> "iconbox_content",
        "value"=>"",
        "description" => esc_html__( "IconBox Content Goes Here", 'ew') 
    ),
```

So i guess, the other half of what i did is very logical already, but here it is anyway:

I added an array in this file:

```
    array(
        "type"=>'textarea',
        "heading"=>esc_html__('Price', 'ew'),
        "param_name"=> "iconbox_price",
        "value"=>"",
        "description" => esc_html__( "Price goes here", 'ew')   
    ),
```

And in the first file:
To extract `"iconbox_price" =>'',`

And lower: `echo '<p class="iconbox_price">'.$iconbox_price .'</p>' ;`

Wish that this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

You see the line there:

```
echo '<p'.$content_style.'>'.$iconbox_content .'</p>' ;
```

You can add your custom paragraph to that line:

```
echo '<p'.$content_style.'>'.$iconbox_content .'</p>
<p style='iconbox_price'></p>' ;
```

Comment: That way the site just goes down.
And even if I add another line after the first one you wrote like this:
echo '<p'.$content_style.'>'.$iconbox_content .'</p>
echo '<p style="iconbox_price"></p>' ;
It wont give a field in the admin panel to fill it out.

Comment: Change ' to " in p tag

Comment: Yeah, I did that. But it wont give any field or place where i can edit it from the admin panel. I'm sure at least there should be some variables and probably some code for it to work

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. But I did it in a very different way. I'll write down the solution right now.